# Jhipster related query

Tags: jhipster

Can i use javascript instead of typescript in Jhipster tool .I have set the environment and project structure where I found typescript is being used as a file for react side , so my qus is can we have a project skeleton of javascript instead of typescript.pls respond?

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure JHipster to generate frontend code in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using an old version of JHipster (and Angular instead of React), [JHipster 4](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/v4.x_maintenance) can generate your client-side using AngularJS.

Install the latest version 4.x locally:

```sh
npm i generator-jhipster@4.14.5
```

Create an application:

```sh
jhipster
```

When prompted about the frontend framework, choose `AngularJS`:

```sh
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client?
  Angular 5
> AngularJS 1.x
```

If you must absolutely use javascript, I think this is the easiest way.